# Transfer RFID tag no. to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, c, http, arduino

I am having tough time to transfer my RFID tag no. to mysql database. When I compile the given code server gets connected so and prints the rfid no. and also says data sent to server but when I open my php file (also mysql) there is no data stored. What am I doing wrong!! P.s sorry for my bad english.

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Client.h>
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial RFID(2,3);
int i;
int rfid;
char newtag[14];// = {2,49,51,48,48,57,69,66,48,51,57,48,52,3};
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte subnet[] = {255,255,255,0};
//IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
//IPAddress DBserver(192, 168, 1, 2);
IPAddress server(192,168,1,7);
//char server[] = "localhost/te";
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,2);
EthernetClient client;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    RFID.begin(9600);
    delay (1000);
    Serial.print("*********Initializing Ethernet*********n");
    if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0)
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
        Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    }
    //Ethernet.begin(mac, server, gateway);
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("connecting...");
    Serial.print("IP Address:");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
    Serial.print("Subnet Mask:");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.subnetMask());
    Serial.print("Default Gateway IP:");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.gatewayIP());
    Serial.print("DNS Server IP:");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.dnsServerIP());
}
void loop()
{
    // while(1)
    {
        if (client.connect(server, 80))
        {
            Serial.print("Connected to server:");
            Serial.println(Ethernet.dnsServerIP());
            while(1)
            {
                if (RFID.available() > 0)
                {
                    Serial.println("reading rfid tags");
                    delay(100);
                    for (i=0; i < 14; i++)
                    {
                        rfid = RFID.read();
                        newtag[i]=rfid;
                    }
                    RFID.flush();
                    Serial.print("rfid tag no:");
                    Serial.print(newtag);
                    Serial.println("Sending to Server...");
                    client.println("GET 192.168.1.7/te/add_data.php?sensor=2323 HTTP/1.1");
                    client.print(newtag);
                    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
                    client.println("Host: 192.168.1.7/te/");
                    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino");
                    client.println("Accept: text/html");
                    Serial.println("data sent to server");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Cannot connect to Server");
        }
    }
```

and my php code is

```
<?php
    // Start MySQL Connection   
    include('dbconnect.php'); 
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Log</title>    
    <style type="text/css">    
        .table_titles, .table_cells_odd, .table_cells_even {    
                padding-right: 20px;    
                padding-left: 20px;    
                color: #000;    
        }    
        .table_titles {    
            color: #FFF;    
            background-color: #666;    
        }    
        .table_cells_odd {    
            background-color: #CCC;    
        }    
        .table_cells_even {    
            background-color: #FAFAFA;    
        }    
        table {    
            border: 2px solid #333;    
        }    
        body { font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial; }    
    </style>    
</head>    
    <body>    
        <h1>Arduino  Log</h1>    
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">    
      <tr>
           <td class="table_titles">ID</td>    
            <td class="table_titles">Date and Time</td>
            <td class="table_titles">RFID tag</td>
      </tr>
<?php    
    // Retrieve all records and display them
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM FYP ORDER BY id ASC");
    // Used for row color toggle
    $oddrow = true;
    // process every record
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
    {
        if ($oddrow) 
        { 
            $css_class=' class="table_cells_odd"'; 
        }
        else
        { 
            $css_class=' class="table_cells_even"';

        }
        $oddrow = !$oddrow;
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '   <td'.$css_class.'>'.$row["id"].'</td>';
        echo '   <td'.$css_class.'>'.$row["event"].'</td>';
        echo '   <td'.$css_class.'>'.$row["tag"].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please correct the indentation (and remove all those blank lines). Please.

Comment: This looks like C code that runs on your Arduino and implements a very simple subset of the HTTP protocol. Is that correct?  I think your GET request should not contain your host's ip address. I think it's possible your php program never gets hit because of that.

Comment: what should I write in-place of GET then!!!

Comment: Have you shown us the code for `te/add_data.php`?  I cannot find the place where you accept the data from your arduino in the code you have furnished.

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing HTTP line by line in your C++ program. It's probably helpful for your learning to look up the appropriate RFCs even if they're a little hard to read.  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5

Given the GET request you've shown us, your `add_data.php` program needs to accept the `$_REQUEST['sensor']` parameter. I can't find where you do that.

Your HTTP client program, on your Arduino, needs to send this kind of block to your web server running your php program.  First, it opens a connection to the server. You seem to have done this correctly on port 80. Then it sends something like this.

```
GET /te/add_data.php?sensor=2323 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: 192.168.1.7\r\n
User-Agent: Arduino\r\n
Accept: text/html\r\n
\r\n
```

Notice two things.

1. Your payload -- your useful information being sent to the php program -- is entirely in the GET line.
2. Each line needs to end with carriage return/newline. And, at the end of the request block, there needs to be a blank line that ends with an extra carriage return / newline.

Your C++ code -- your `client.println()` code -- doesn't seem to do that. In particular, the value of `newtag` will be misplaced in your request block.

Notice also that the only item of data you're sending to the php program is 'sensor', and you're sending it the hard-coded value `2323`. I can't tell from your program exactly what you're trying to do. But what you're doing isn't very interesting, so maybe it's a test to get things working.

I hope this helps. When you get it working, you will have implemented a reasonably complex system.